# Can FileStream create zero-fill files when Windows crashes?

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems

I have received several reports from users of C# applications that their data was corrupted when Windows crashed while the application was running (e.g., the notebook PC was turned off, forced to quit, etc.).
When I looked at the data, strangely enough, the file size was the same as the normal one, but all the contents were filled with zero.
Is it possible that such a file could be generated from the following code?

```cs
var tempFilePath = $"{path}.temp";

using (var stream = File.Open(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
} // Flush should be done automatically in Dispose

// Originally it was not via temp file, but after receiving the report, it is now via temp file.
// Still did not resolve the issue.
File.Copy(tempFilePath, path, true);
File.Delete(tempFilePath);
```

Since no .temp file was left, it is considered to have run to delete normally.
The file size is small even when normal, less than 300 bytes. (Is it possible that its small size prevents it from being written to disk from the cache?)

I found this article but thought this was irrelevant because of copying to anotherdisk.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190517-00/?p=102500

Comment: Yes it can, if the data is not flushed to disk. There are many buffers involved, which only get flsuhed if the stream is closed. Meanwhile the actual size may already have been set in the file system. Clearly the crash happened before the end of `using`. Alternatively, you have an old consumer-grade SSD, which reports data as being flushed when it actually isn't

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

I feel the same too.
If they are crashing before the end of using, then the copy should not run, so there is no problem.
But, I have received far too many reports to consider it an SSD failure….

Comment: Does your code perhaps not have an `await`? Perhaps you should look at what creates `bytes`, maybe it isn't generating properly.

Comment: Yes...I will check the various possibilities again. Thanks.